# Morris Chart STacked Chart x axis redundancy

Tags: php, jquery, morris.js

[image]

I've been working out a graph that will display on how many item I sell per week and per month,
I am getting what I want to display the problem is this Morris Stacked Chart displaying the week(number of weeks) redundantly. How can I solve this?
my database is in that image

**PHP QUERY**

```
 $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT item_sku, sell_week, sell_month, sell FROM product_progress GROUP BY item_sku, sell_week");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  $chart_data .= "{ week:'".$row['sell_week']."',sku:'".$row["item_sku"]."',purchase:".$row["sell"]."},";
 }
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 Morris.Bar({
    element : 'chart',
    data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
    xkeys: 'week',
    ykeys:['purchase', 'purchase'],
    labels:['Purchase', 'Week'],
    lineColors: ['#1e88e5','#ff3321'],
    lineWidth: '3px',
    hideHover:'auto',
    stacked:true
 });
```

Comment: Are you sure that you use the correct data? You should clarify whether this is a question about finding the proper data to be shown or displaying the proper data in the format you need

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data coming from PHP backend?

Comment: mr @beaver my database consist of 3 item which is saved on its sell count per week now i have 12 data in my DB(sell_count of 3 items in 4 weeks)

Comment: Click on that image to see what i really want to show in my chart :(

Comment: Could you create a CodePen or a Fiddle about that issue? Or just post an image about the *«Morris Stacked Chart displaying the week(number of weeks) redundantly»* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line of data should contain all the info for that week.

Example: `{ week: 1, item_1: 10, item_2: 8, item_3: 20 }`

All these columns should be declared in the *ykeys* of Morris.Bar.

Thus I suppose the fix would be rather in your SQL than in javascript ;-)